# Tensorflow: Build-in Losses object works but custom/build-in Loss function doesn't work

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm using the tensorflow2 to train a model with custom loss:

Loss:

```
def new_loss_orig(self, y_true, y_pred):
    mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))
    return mse
def new_loss_mixup(self, y_true, y_pred, long_run_pred):
    w_1 = 0.3
    w_2 = 0.7
    mse = tf.reduce_mean(w_1*tf.square(y_true - y_pred) + w_2*tf.square(long_run_pred-y_pred))
    return mse
def new_loss_wmse(self, y_true, y_pred):
    return
```

Model:

```
    with tf.device(self.device):
        inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(X_train_arr.shape[1]))
        x = LayerNormalization()(inputs)
        x = Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
        x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, tf.reshape(inputs[:, -1], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = Dense(1)(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([x, tf.reshape(inputs[:, -1], (-1, 1))], axis=-1)
        x = BatchNormalization()(x)
        outputs = Dense(1)(x)
        model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs,outputs)

        # Define loss function and optimizer
        optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam()
```

Train process:

```
           # Define our metrics
        train_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='train_loss')
        val_loss = tf.keras.metrics.Mean(name='val_loss')

        # Batch size and preparation of dataset
        batch_size = 10000
        train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train_arr, Y_train_arr)).shuffle(X_train_arr.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)
        val_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_val_arr, Y_val_arr)).shuffle(X_val_arr.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)

        # Initialize the early stopping parameters
        best_val_loss = float('inf')
        patience = 2
        counter = 0
        # Training loop
        for epoch in range(5):
            print(f'Start of epoch {epoch}')
            # Iterate over the batches of the dataset
            for step, (x_batch_train, y_batch_train) in tqdm(enumerate(train_dataset)):
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    y_batch_pred_train = model(x_batch_train, training=True)
                    if self.new_loss == 'orig':
                        loss_value = self.new_loss_orig(y_batch_train, y_batch_pred_train)
                    elif self.new_loss == 'mixup':
                        # scale from [-50, 50] to [-10, 10]
                        long_run_batch_pred_train = x_batch_train[:, -1]/5
                        loss_value = self.new_loss_mixup(y_batch_train, y_batch_pred_train, long_run_batch_pred_train)
                    elif self.new_loss == 'wmse':
                        loss_value = self.new_loss_wmse(y_batch_train, y_batch_pred_train)
                grads = tape.gradient(loss_value, model.trainable_weights)
                optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_weights))
                train_loss(loss_value)

            # Validation step
            for x_batch_val, y_batch_val in tqdm(val_dataset):
                y_batch_pred_val = model(x_batch_val, training=False)
                if self.new_loss == 'orig':
                    v_loss_value = self.new_loss_orig(y_batch_val, y_batch_pred_val)
                elif self.new_loss == 'mixup':
                    # scale from [-50, 50] to [-10, 10]
                    long_run_batch_pred_val = x_batch_val[:, -1] / 5
                    v_loss_value = self.new_loss_mixup(y_batch_val, y_batch_pred_val, long_run_batch_pred_val)
                elif self.new_loss == 'wmse':
                    v_loss_value = self.new_loss_wmse(y_batch_val, y_batch_pred_val)
                val_loss(v_loss_value)

            print(f'Epoch {epoch}, Train Loss: {train_loss.result()}, Val Loss: {val_loss.result()}')

            # Check if we need to stop training
            current_val_loss = val_loss.result()
            if current_val_loss < best_val_loss:
                best_val_loss = current_val_loss
                counter = 0  # reset counter
            else:
                counter += 1  # increment counter
                if counter >= patience:
                    print('Early stopping due to no improvement in validation loss')
                    break
        
            # Reset metrics at the end of each epoch
            train_loss.reset_states()
            val_loss.reset_states()
```

The loss new_loss_orig is mse in fact, and I use new_loss_origin to train the model.

But unfortunely, the model cannot converge, after training, the result is silimair with random prediction.

When I changed the loss function new_loss_orig to a build-in object tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(), the model converges and can predict meaningful values.

I suppose that my implementation may be wrong, so i use tf.keras.losses.mean_squared_error and kf.keras.metric.mean_squared_error, however, it works as new_loss_orig, too, which doesn't seem like converged. But when i print the `grads`, all are not none and not zero.

I wonder what happened and how to solve the problem.

Comment: Please do not include text as images, only as plain text.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have updated, thank u!

Comment: You should also clearly state the problem, not with vague statements like "doesn't work" or "works as expected".

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Thank u again, i clarify my question. When use loss function, the model doesn't coverge. but grads are not none or zeros.